# How to check in Python if the value in a key value pair of a dict is a list or a string

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an object like this

```
ds_obj = {
              "Labels" : 
                [ 
                    {
                        "Label" : "pop",
                        "People" : {
                          "Composer" : "John"
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "Label" : "classical",
                        "People" : {
                          "Composer" : [ "Johann", "Jason" ]
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        "Label" : "classical-2",
                        "People" : {
                          "Composer" : [ "Jacob" ]
                        },
                    }        
                ]
            }
```

I need to iterate thru each of the labels and perform some actions on each of the composers, but first I need to find out if each label has a single composer or multiple. To do this I am running the following code to find out if the key `Composer` has an array or a string. If it has an array, I will run a nested loop thru it and work with each composer. The code below however is calling out every value as an array. What is wrong with my code? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
    for label in ds_obj ['Labels']:
        if hasattr(label['People']['Composer'], "__len__"):
            print('IS ARRAY')
        else:
            print('NOT Array')
```

Comment: `["Johann", "Jason"]` is a list (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) rather than an array (https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).

Comment: You shouldn't let the value be a string; even if it's just one person, you should still store it as a list `["John"]`, so that consumers don' have to worry about values of different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

`if isinstance(label['People']['Composer'], list):`

Python strings also have a `__len__` attribute so your code is true for both lists and strings.

Answer (score 0):

You're currently checking if composer has a length. Both strings and lists have lengths, so `hasattr(..., '__len__')` will return True in both cases.

You can just check if the type is equal to List.:

```
for label in ds_obj ['Labels']:
    if type(label['People']['Composer']) is list:
        print('Array')
    else: 
        print('NOT Array')
```

Comment: The `else` should be indented to line up with the `if`

Comment: Messed up while pasting, thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Don't compare types directly. Use `isinstance`.

Comment: @chepner: why not compare types? Is there some issue with using `type` over  `isinstance` ? Sorry for noob question. Not too familiar with the internals of Python.

Comment: Comparing types precludes using subclasses correctly. if `type(a)` is a subclass of `list`, then `isinstance(a, list)` is true, but `type(a) is list` is not.